# How to call a controller function in another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller Export that extends CI_Controller and another controller called Magento_Attribute_Set that extends CI_Controller too.

I need to call `export_attributes()` function from Magento_Attribute_Set within Export controller.

I have read similar questions here but they do not make sense to me and I have never worked with codeigniter framework before.

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me please.

Comment: Why not put it in the parent controller (CI_Controller) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call a function from one controller in another, that means your code is not organized correctly.

You cannot (at least without dirty hacks) call/load a controller from another one.

What you should do is move the `export_attributes()` elsewhere, somewhere both controllers can read it.  Consider a library or a helper, depending on what the function does.